# Turn on Replay Log Debugger fails in Visual Studio Code

Tags: vs-code, apex-replay-debugger

I'm getting an error when trying to use the 'turn on Apex debug log for replay debugger' command in Visual Studio Code.

VS-Code version 1.15.2

sfdx-cli version sfdx-cli/7.98.0 linux-x64 node-v15.14.0

when using the command;

```
SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger
```

The process starts ok but appears to fail when trying to set trace flags, complaining the flag has already been set.

Full error text is [here](https://pastebin.com/YSFGYYtr)

Does anyone know how I can get past this and turn on the replay debugger?

Comment: I updated my VS-Code version + cli version and this issue went away

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to use all the manual commands to be able to debug, you can [just click **Run debugger** in VsCode SFDX Hardis extension](https://medium.com/p/12237c0638b7) :)

[image]

Disclaimer: my company is the author of the VsCode extension